# Why the content in the layout designer does not fit the emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I used the Android Studio design layout editor having gridLayout within the RelativeLayout, added 4 buttons horizontally. It appears fine in the Android Studio layout designer but when I ran it in the virtual emulator or a Samsung phone not all the buttons fit in the screen.
How do you make it work for all android phones? 
Is it not WYSIWYG?

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize the grid layout content using the device screen sizes. Which means change the buttons width related to screen width. Also you can achieve this using Frame Layout.